# Converting a BigDecimal Number to the format of ###.#

Tags: java, methods, number-formatting

I am trying to make a number in a BigDecimal variable match the format of ###.# where no matter what number is passed it will come out as ###.#

For example, if I was passed the number 1 in a BigDecimal variable the method would return 001.0

If I was passed 11.1 as a BigDecimal variable the method would return 011.1

I already have a bit of the code to make the decimal places match

`BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal(1); 
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.0");
String formatted = df.format(x);`

So this would return 1.0 however I cannot figure out how to make the leading zeros appear before converting back to BigDecimal.

Can someone help me out or point me in the right direction?

Thanks everyone

Comment: Could you clarify a bit more? The answers posted works as expected, per requirement.
"using a variable instead of a number", what does that mean?

Comment: Per my example code above, I have a BigDecimal variable x. I need to format x as 000.0. However, If I use df.format(x) and then turn x back into a BigDecimal the formatting goes away. Example: X = 1 after using the format it turns into 001.0 which is what is needed. When converting it back to BigDecimal it turns into 1.0 which is incorrect.

Comment: BigDecimal **does not** have the concept of formatting. That is obviously lost after conversion to BigDecimal. BigDecimal just hold a number.

Comment: I figured it out with the help of Andreas. Thank you so much. The solution I came up with was `df.format(myVariable.getMyVariable()).toString()` . I know that may not make a ton of sense but unfortunately that is all I can share due to my company's privacy laws. Thanks everyone!

Comment: You're doing something non-sense, you are calling toString on a String. But whatever.

Comment: Yes I am well aware of what I am doing and have already changed my code before I was even aware of your condescending remark. With all due respect, I don’t need your condescension. I came here to ask for help amongst my peers on a problem I was having not to have someone be completely rude and unprofessional. If you see something I’m doing wrong then please let me know so I can fix that but you don’t have to be so condescending. Thanks to everyone else who helped. I have learned from my errors and your advice. Thread closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `new DecimalFormat("000.0")`

*Examples*

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("000.0", DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.US));
System.out.println(df.format(new BigDecimal("1")));       // prints: 001.0
System.out.println(df.format(new BigDecimal("11.1")));    // prints: 011.1
System.out.println(df.format(new BigDecimal("123.456"))); // prints: 123.5
System.out.println(df.format(new BigDecimal(".07")));     // prints: 000.1
System.out.println(df.format(new BigDecimal("123456")));  // prints: 123456.0
```

Comment: So the only problem with using this method is that I will be using a variable instead of a number. So for example BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal(1); so I can't do new BigDecimal(x). Sorry for the confusion. I will restate my problem in the main post

Answer (score 1):

Use a `NumberFormat` instance, with a `Locale` which uses the *dot* as decimal separator.

```
final BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal("11.1");

final NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(1);
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(1);
nf.setMinimumIntegerDigits(3);

final String formatted = nf.format(x);
```

`NumberFormat` is basically a Factory, so for example in this case the underlying formatter returned by `getNumberInstance` is a `DecimalFormat`. I always prefer being abstracted off the real implementation.

You can also decide if you want to display the grouping comma or not.

```
nf.setGroupingUsed(true);   // 123,456.0 - default value is true
nf.setGroupingUsed(false);  // 123456.0
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the StringUtils of apache.

```
StringUtils.leftPad(number.toString(), 3, '0');
```

Where the first argument is the String to format, second argument is the number of to left places to validate, and the last argument is the char for complete.

Reggards.

Comment: I think you meant `StringUtils.leftPad(number.toString(), 5, '0');`

Comment: That's not really an appropriate solution.